# Summary statistics of numeric variables in data frame in specific format

Tags: r

I have a data frame and there are 3 numeric variables there. I need to calculate some parameters of these numeric variables like mean, median, std, kurtosis. And then I need to arrange this in a data frame. So, first column of this data frame will contain all numeric variable names and second column will contain all mean values, third column will contain all median values and so on. How can this be achieved ? I am familiar with `dplyr` package. So any suggestions ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `summarise` with `across` :

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

mtcars %>%
  select(1:3) %>%
  summarise(across(where(is.numeric), list(mean = mean, std = sd, med = median)))

#  mpg_mean  mpg_std mpg_med cyl_mean  cyl_std cyl_med disp_mean disp_std disp_med
#1 20.09062 6.026948    19.2   6.1875 1.785922       6  230.7219 123.9387    196.3
```

In the older version of `dplyr`, you can use `summarise_if` :

```
mtcars %>%
  select(1:3) %>%
  summarise_if(is.numeric, list(mean = mean, std = sd, med = median))
```

---

You can add `pivot_longer` to above answer to get data in required format.

```
mtcars %>%
  select(1:3) %>%
  summarise(across(where(is.numeric),list(mean=mean,std=sd,med = median))) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = everything(), 
               names_to = c('col', '.value'), 
               names_sep = '_')


# A tibble: 3 x 4
#  col     mean    std   med
#  <chr>  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
#1 mpg    20.1    6.03  19.2
#2 cyl     6.19   1.79   6  
#3 disp  231.   124.   196.
```

Or you can first pivot and then do the calculation :

```
mtcars %>%
  select(1:3) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = everything()) %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  summarise(mean = mean(value), std = sd(value), med = median(value))
```

Comment: I actually tried to use `across`, but the format is not what I wanted. It just gives one single row. I want all variable names in the first column, then all mean values in the second column and all median values in the 3rd column and so on.